# Adapter for NTC boiler probe

Tags: plumbing, hvac, boiler, tankless, connectors

I just bought a replacement NTC probe for my boiler (bought with specific part number) but once the item arrived I noticed the connector wasn't matching. I think this is due to past maintenance when the original probe was probably replaced by a 'compatible' one along with the wire.

Now I want to replace that probe because my boiler does not modulate any more on DHW but it does on space heating. So the first suspected is that (faulty) probe.

Said that, this is a photo of boiler's connector and with new probe on the side. I'm asking if someone could tell me what connector (or adaptor) should I get to install it.[image: probe]

Answer (score -1):

All manufacturers that I know of have a service line.

Your best bet is to contact the original manufactures service line and see what they have to say about it. You may have to purchase a new harness along with your element.